# Error building a C/C++ application with COMPSs: Hardcoded path

Tags: distributed-computing, hpc, compss

I am trying to build a COMPSs application developed with the C/C++ binding. When I am building the application, I got the following error. Do you have an idea about how can I solve this issue?

```
xxxx:~/xxx/c/increment> buildapp increment
*---------------------------------------------------------------------*
*                                                                     *
*               BSC - Barcelona Supercomputing Center                 *
*                          COMP Superscalar                           *
*                                                                     *
*                  C/C++ Applications - BUILD SCRIPT                  *
*                                                                     *
*                                                                     *
*  More information at COMP Superscalar Website: http://compss.bsc.es *
*                                                                     *
*  Support: support-compss@bsc.es                                     *
*                                                                     *
*  Dependencies: csh (sudo apt-get install csh)                       *
*                                                                     *
*---------------------------------------------------------------------*

ARCH: amd64
SUBFLDR: server
Cleaning intermediate files...
rm -f *.o
Building application for master...
g++ -DCOMPSS_MASTER -std=c++11 -g -I. -I/opt/COMPSs/Bindings/c/include -I/opt/COMPSs/Bindings/bindings-common/include -c example.cc
ar rvs libmaster.a example.o
ar: creating libmaster.a
a - example.o
ranlib libmaster.a
Building application for workers...
g++ -DCOMPSS_WORKER -std=c++11 -g -I. -I/opt/COMPSs/Bindings/c/include -I/opt/COMPSs/Bindings/bindings-common/include -c example.cc
ar rvs libworker.a example.o
ar: creating libworker.a
a - example.o
ranlib libworker.a
Deploying lib files...
/home/jorgee/margarita_svn/bar/tutorial_apps/c/increment
Building all:

Building Master...
The master directory already exists from a previous build. Removing.
/usr/bin/cp: cannot stat ‘/home/cramonco/svn/compss/framework/tags/1.4/builders/specs/rpm/compss-c-binding/tmp/BUILDROOT/compss-c-binding-1.4-1.x86_64/opt/COMPSs/Bindings/c/share/compsuperscalar/build/c/master/Makefile.am’: No such file or directory
ERROR: Command exited with status 1.

Building binding failed, please check errors above!
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a problem that appears when installing from deb or rpm packages. Some scripts have been installed with the compilation paths. To solve it, you have two options:

Reinstall from sources the 1.4 patched version:

```
wget http://compss.bsc.es/releases/compss/1.4/patches/COMPSs_1.4_07_update.tgz

tar zxvf COMPSs_1.4_07_update.tgz

cd 1.4_07/builders

sudo -E ./buildlocal
```

or execute the following command

```
sudo sed -i "s|$HOME/svn/compss/framework/tags/1.4/builders/specs/rpm/compss-c-binding/tmp/BUILDROOT/compss-c-binding-1.4-1.x86_64||g" /opt/COMPSs/Bindings/c/bin/gsbuild
```